# Show that for each $p\geq1$, $\exists \text{ a sequence } a_n$ such that $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum |a_n^p|$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to come up with a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\forall p\geq1$, $\exists \text{ a  sequence } a_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n^p|$ diverges. There was a hint saying to play around with the form $\frac{(-1)^n}{n^q}$, but I don't quite see how this helps.

By alternating series test, since $\lim \frac{1}{n^q} = 0$ and since $\frac{1}{n^q}$ is decreasing as n gets larger, we have convergence. So $\sum a_n$ converges.

For the $\sum a_n^p$ case, we have $\lim \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{pq}}$, but wouldn't this still converge since $p>1$?

Comment: What if you take $q=1/(2p)$?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something but if $ q = \frac{1}{2p}$, then for the case $\sum a_n^p$ we would have $\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/2}}$. Wouldn't this still converge under the alternating series test?

Comment: Yes. You may want to check what the alternating series test says. But also, the series that needs to converge is without the power p, as per your question. The one tgat will diverge has the power p, and more crucially has absolute values.

Comment: Oh wait. I think I see it now. With the absolute values, we will have $\frac{1}{\sqrt {n} }$. This is simply a p series with $p \leq 1$. So it diverges. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @ClementC. Oh I have a quick follow-up question. For the alternating series test, we have $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{(1/(2p)}}$. Then wouldn't $\lim \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2p}}}$ diverge since our power in this case is less than 1? And so the case without the power doesn't converge?

Comment: But the alternating series test only asks for 3 things: (1) alternating signs (2) limit being 0 and (3) absolute values forming a non-increasing sequence.

Comment: @ClementC. Forgive I'm messing something up, but I understand that the limit goes to 0 if the series converges. In this case, the $\lim b_n$ in the alternating series test would be $\lim \frac{1}{n^{1/(2p)}}$, which diverges by the power test since our power is less than 1 for certain cases of $p>1$ because of the $\frac{1}{2}$ and hence does not go to zero.

Comment: ? Set $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/2p}}$. The series $\sum_n a_n$ converges (conditionally) because of the alternating series test, as it (1) alternates signs, (2) has $a_n \to 0$ and (3) has $(|a_n|_n$ being a decreasing sequence. However, the series $\sum_n |a_n|^p=\sum_{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges, since it is a $p$-series with $p<1$.

Comment: You are confusing two things. In the second case, because of the absolute values the series is a $p$-series which diverges. In the first, it is *not* a $p$-series because of the $(-1)^n$ which makes it an alternating series.